# PHP rand explanation using an array?

Tags: php

I have very little programming experience but I am going over a php book and this block of code is confusing me.

If rand generates a random integer, how does this program use ABCDEFG in the array.
Can you please explain the program thank you. I know what the result is, I am just not sure how it get it.

```
<?php

$array = '123456789ABCDEFG';

$s = '';

    for ($i=1; $i < 50; $i++) { 
        $s.= $array[rand(0,strlen($array)-1)]; //explain please

}

echo $s;

?>
```

Comment: strings in PHP can be used as arrays. You can ask for the nth character just as you ask for the nth element of an array

Answer (score 5):

It's using the array index so `$array[11]` would equal `'C'`. `rand()` takes a range - in your example that's from `0` to `strlen($array)-1` which is the length of the string, minus 1 since it's a 0 based index.

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into parts:

```
strlen($array) - returns the length of the string in $array, which would be 17
strlen($array) - 1  => 16

rand(0, 16) - generate a random number between 0 and 16

$array[$random_number] - get the $random_number'th element of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just taking the length of the array with `strlen($array)`. It doesn't matter what is in the string just the length. Then its generating a random number between 0 and the length of the string minus one.

Then it takes whatever character is in that position in the array (so `$array[5]` would be `'6'`, `$array[12]` would be `'C'`, etc) and appending that to string `$s`. It then has a for loop to repeat it 50 times.

What you end up with is a random string that is 50 characters long and contains the numbers 1-9 and letters A-G.